# Books to inspire you to get out in nature

Tags: books

What are some inspiring books by naturalists that write about nature and its trans formative qualities in such a way that you can;t just wait to get out there? I am not looking for books in extreme adventure and sports but something more within my reach. I know John Muir is a noted naturalist but before buying any of his books, I wanted to get a recommendation from you all.

Comment: This is not a constructive question. Read the closure notice below for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"list" questions can cause problems on stackexchange sites, but, anyhow...

From a UK perspective, Robert Macfarlane's ["The Wild Places"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001RNI2F4) is excellent.

Answer (score 4):

Ernest Thompson Seton's book, like [Rolf in the Woods](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1088) or [Two Little Savages](http://www.gutenberg.org/catalog/world/readfile?fk_files=1491860) are inspiration for backwoodmanship, especially for young people.

Comment: E.T. Seton is a local legend here in Toronto. I will check this out

Answer (score 3):

Peter Mathiessen's [The Snow Lepoard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Snow_Leopard).

I actually read it after (not before) trekking from Pokhara to the Dolpo region in Nepal, but I think it meets your description of a book that "just makes you want to get out there". It's an excellent description of what it was like to make that journey thirty years earlier (around 1973). It's not just an inspiring book about journeys and nature (and a very elusive species of big cat) but also deals a lot with Buddhist themes and in a manner that's very approachable for someone who isn't familiar with them (like me).

Comment: Just read the book. Became one of my favorites. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

[Hatchet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0689826990) - by  Gary Paulsen

This one get me hooked at a young age.

Answer (score 3):

[Curious naturalists](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0870234560) by Niko Tinbergen. This is one of the best books on ethology of animals, pleasure to read for anyone. It motivates to study and observe animals in their natural habitat. I was especially delighted by the story of [hobby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobby_%28bird%29) family or the interesting life of sand wasps.

Answer (score 3):

*Of Water and Spirit* from Malidoma Patrice Somé. Although this book is not explicitly about nature, it is about people who live in unity with it. There is one very strong moment in the book that inspires very strongly for contact with nature, and very deeply describes its transformative qualities. You will not be dissapointed.