# Are there any outdoorsy comics?

Tags: books

I know there are many outdoor-related adventure novels that can make great company while relaxing on one's own adventure, but are there any outdoorsy comic books?

Perhaps the hero is a hiker with an ability to control the elements or understand animals, helps people and animals in danger, fights evil corporations trying to ruin our natural resources, etc.

Comment: I could have brainstormed for weeks to list questions that might be asked on this site, and I wouldn't have come up with that one.

Comment: Well, there's Mark Trail. Not sure it comes in book form, and he's got no special powers.

Comment: @DonBranson: It seems that Mark Trail comic books were published in the late 1950s, and not since.

Comment: I think this question is off-topic here. It has nothing to do with wilderness - one can read comics in the lunch break in the office. Maybe fit to Fantasy.SE or some such. For example compare with this [question](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/books-to-inspire-you-to-get-out-in-nature), which is IMO much more on-topic here, but is closed.

Comment: @Vorac: I understand it may be stretching the topic a little, but the main point is for a comic that is "wilderness" inspired. Sure, books and comics can be read elsewhere - a person can also start a fire using flint & steel outside of the wilderness as well.

Comment: Does it have to be in English?

Comment: @Jan: Yes, in English would be good. But if you know of non-English ones, please share as they may be of interest to others.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know of specific comic books other than [Ultralight Backpackin' Tips](http://ultralightbackpackintips.blogspot.com/) which has cartoon illustrations. However it is far from a comic book. :-)

[WhiteBlaze](http://whiteblaze.net/) features some [comic strips about hiking/thru-hiking](http://bootsmcfarland.com/Cartoons.html) on their website. And others have also made some hiking-related comics such as [Keith Roberts](http://www.whiteblaze.net/forum/archive/index.php/t-74523.html?s=ea60d5d66fd924422b4d99093abea199).